Azure Open AI: Error when calling completions api with GPT4o-mini
I am getting the following error when calling completions api with GPT4o-mini model.
`{
"error": {
"code": "OperationNotSupported",
"message": "The completion operation does not work with the specified model, gpt-4o-mini. Please choose different model and try again. You can learn more about which models can be used with each operation here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2197993."
}
}`
If I use an older model like GPT3.5, I get no errors.
The endpoint I am using is similar to https://dev-swedencentral-openai.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/dev-gpt-4o-mini/completions?api...
I saw that at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/overview
it says that GPT4o-mini is already supported.
Can you help to solve this error?
Thanks
Chaging the deployment model to GPT 3.5 gives no error but I want to use GPT4o-mini.

This question is similar to: Why am I getting invalid model error with "gpt-35-turbo-16k" model in Azure Open AI but not with "gpt-35-turbo"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Use ChatCompletions endpoint, not Completions endpoint with GPT models
